# How to disable Windows 10 update + defender completely?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I must say, I'm pretty angry at Microsoft given that its background processes continuously crash *Age of Empires* and doesn't let me play ranked.

I wanna completely disable all updates, all security measures, everything. Yesterday I traced back the crash event to a forced Windows Defender background update, so I turned off some parts of the Defender in the registry.

And after a while, Windows always finds a way to force the default settings on me.

I wanna have control over my operating system since I've paid for it…

My question is *what* is the missing piece here? What *else* do I need to disable?

Picture: Windows forcefully changes back registry to defaults.

[image: Windows agressively forces Defender updates]

Comment: I recommend fixing the actual problem (crashes in AoE) instead.

Comment: The actual problem is Windows. I've seen the event log. Windows takes away hardware resources during forced random updates, and the game clock goes out of sync because of that.

Answer (score 1):

While I can tell you ways to disable Updates and Defender in Windows 10, the practice is not recommended.

Disable Defender

https://github.com/ionuttbara/windows-defender-remover

Use the option to Only Disable, do not remove

Disable updates. Use SlegdeHammer 2.7.2

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/wumt_wrapper_script.html

To run both these tools, you may need admin privileges.

I have a system with Windows 10 where Defender and Updates are perpetually disabled using these two tools.

Note that when you run SledgeHammer the tool also disables MS Store downloads. There’s an option in the tool to temporarily allow MS Store apps downloads if you need to before downloading an app from MS Store.

If you are not sure, I suggest try these tools first in a Windows 10 VM to get a feel how do they work.

Note that you need to install both these tools ideally for defender to be stopped, because even if you disable defender and leave updates ON, upon next update the settings could reset back to Enabled state.

Answer (score 0):

> And after a while, Windows always finds a way to force the default
> settings on me.

For modern Windows 10 (22H2 or better) and more so for Windows 11 and for consumer machines (not Company), updates and Defender will always restart running at some point.

What you see is completely normal and cannot be permanently changed on a consumer computer.

You can whitelist any Apps that you need to run in the normal course of your activities.

Potential duplicate article about this are several years old.

Answer (score -1):

To disable Defender from checking in the background while
you're using the computer,
you need to disable "Real-time protection", like this :

- Run *Settings > Privacy & security > Windows Security*
- Click "Virus & threat protection"
- In the *Virus & threat protection* window, under
  "Virus & threat protection settings" click "Manage settings"
- In the *Virus & threat protection settings* window, set
  "Real-time protection" and "Dev Drive protection" to Off.

The effect is immediate, no reboot required.
While this setting is in effect, Defender won't do any checks,
although it's still possible to manually start disk scans.

You should undo this when you're not playing the game.